# how select statement works in spring using JdbcTemplate.query(String query, ResultSetExtractor rs) method

Tags: java, spring

using Spring `JdbcTemplate` i execute select statement like this.

```
JdbcTemplate jTemplate = container.getBean("jt", JdbcTemplate.class);
String query = "select *from TB_CUMM_DEAL_CCY_DET where REF_NUM ='1452454'";
jTemplate.query(query, new MyResultSetExtractor());
```

in this code how `jTemplate.query(query, new MyResultSetExtractor());` execute. Please explain any one.

Thank You.

MyResultSetExtractor.java :

```
public class MyResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor {

    @Override
    public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
            DataAccessException {
        String refNo = null;
        while(rs.next()) {
            refNo = rs.getString(2);
            System.out.println(refNo);
        }

        return refNo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ResultSetExtractor will just return one result object for the entire ResultSet. That's the main difference with the RowMappe, which retrieves one object per row.

What your are doing in your ResultSetExtractor is iterating over each row (rs.next()). Once there you have to create the object representing the entire row. For that you have the get methods that provide one certain data type and also receive as argument both an int indicating the column number or an String indicating the column name.

Let's provide a simple example. Imagin we have a table in a database called Person, with two String column: name and surname.

Your Object is:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

Your ResultSetExctractor:

```
public class MyResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<List<Person>> {

    @Override
    public List<Person> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
            DataAccessException {
        List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName(rs.getString(1));
            person.setSurname(rs.getString("surname"));
            result.add(person);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The simpler alternative, with a RowMapper:

```
public class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<Person> {

    @Override  
    public Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {  
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(rs.getString(1));
        person.setSurname(rs.getString("surname"));
        return person;
    };          
}
```